# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Function_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: xml, function, magento, config, fatal-error

I know this question is repeated but it's not solved with me and there's something weird happening,, the code works perfectly on my localhost, but on the online server it throws the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Function_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547
```

my `local/Mycode/Function/Helper/Data.php` is:

```
<?php
class Mycode_Function_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
  public function PrintGridProducts($i, $_product, $pImg, $tempThis, $limit) {
return "";
}
```

and my `local/Mycode/Function/etc/config.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycode_Function>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mycode_Function>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <function>
                <class>Mycode_Function_Helper</class>
            </function>
        </helpers> 
    </global>
</config>
```

my call to the function:

```
<?php
echo Mage::helper('function')->PrintGridProducts($i, $_product, $pImg, $this, 28);
?>
```

any suggestions?? Thank You !

Comment: hi, the clue is in the error - Magento is trying to find a mage helper, change your call to this;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the clue is in the error - Magento is trying to find a mage helper instead of your custom one.

First off, make sure you have activated your module in /app/etc/modules/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mycode_Function>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Mycode_Function>
</modules>
```

Change your config xml to this;

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <mycode_function>
            <class>Mycode_Function_Helper</class>
        </mycode_function>
    </helpers> 
</global>
```

Change your helper function to start with a lowercase letter printGridProducts(

Change your call to this;

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('mycode_function')->printGridProducts($i, $_product, $pImg, $this, 28); ?>
```

Then you have an error in your helper class - you have 'returns' should be 'return'

Comment: when i did this, it crashed in the localhost

Comment: change returns to return in your helper function

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mycode_Function_Helper_Data' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547 ,,, is it case sensitive?

Comment: functions should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: have you enabled the module in /app/etc/modules/Mycode_Function.xml ?

Comment: this wasn't the answer, actually i forgot to upload Mycode.xml ,, thanks dude, am accepting yr answer :) because it helped me

Comment: thanks, ill add the right bit to the answer for anyone else who stumbles on it